# NodeJS + Mongo - get collection / not method foreach

Tags: node.js, mongodb, collections, foreach, mongoose

I would like to display the contents of my collection on a page with a Foreach but i have an error:

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'forEach'

```
my_express.get('/Profil', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {

_articles.findOne({ email : req.user.email }, function(error, articles) {

if (error || !articles) {
    res.render('Profil', {user : req.user, articles : articles});
}

else {
    res.render('Profil', { user: req.user,  articles : articles});
}
```

And my view was:

```
<% articles.forEach( function( content ){ %> 
<p><%= content.Titre %></p>
<p><%= content.Description %></p><% }); %>
```

Comment: Try using `find` instead of `findOne`.

Comment: I try with find, it doesn't work. I received on view page, undefined values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use findOne, the result will be an object, not an array, and "forEach" is a method of the array prototype.  And when you use find, there is no direct callBack, you would have to something like:

```
_articles.find({ email : req.user.email }).toArray(function(error, articles) {
    if (error || !articles) {
        res.render('Profil', {user : req.user, articles : articles});
    } else {
        res.render('Profil', { user: req.user,  articles : articles});
    }
});
```

instead of "toArray" you could use "each" in which case, the callBack will be called once per item and the item will be an object, just like the findOne case.

Hope that helps.